# Public class square Java returnin all "0"

Tags: java, constructor, public

There is a class called Square

```
public class Square
{
private double side;

public Square(double side)
{
    side = side;
}

public double getSide()
{
    return side;
}

public void setSide(double s)
{
    side = s;
}

public double getArea()
{
    return side * side;
}

public double getPerimeter()
{
    return side * 4;
}
```

Another program declared a Square and passed the value 4.0 to the constructor.  It then used the methods of the class to print the length of a side, the area, and the perimeter of the Square object.  The following is what is put out by the program.

length of side: 0.0
area:           0.0
perimeter:      0.0

I think the problem is the "private double side;" line. But I am not for sure. Any other tidbits people could throw in?

Comment: `this.side = side;` else you're assigning the local variable to itself, not to the instance variable.

Comment: Does `side = side` not generate a warning from the compiler?

Answer (score 5):

In the constructor, the parameter `side` will be a local variable. If you want to refer to the *instance variable* `side`, use the **`this` keyword**:

```
public Square(double side)
{
    this.side = side;
}
```

From [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the *current object* — the object whose method or constructor is being called....

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this

```
public Square(double side) {
    this.side = side;
}
```

In your code, side = side just assigns side to itself. Since it is defaulted to equal zero, it just assigns zero to itself.

In the constructor, side is created as a private variable. To access the "side" variable in the class, you have to use this.side. "this" refers to the instance of the class, so "this.side" is telling the code to change the variable side which is a variable of the Square.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. You should use this.side = side, although, your code would be more legible if you renamed one of the two. Either the parameter or the internal value. This is how you could accomplish this and make the code easier to read:

```
public class Square
{
private double side;

public Square(double aSide)
{
    side = aSide; // in here it is obvious which one is the parameter and which one is the private variable
}

public double getSide()
{
    return side;
}

public void setSide(double s)
{
    side = s;
}

public double getArea()
{
    return side * side;
}

public double getPerimeter()
{
    return side * 4;
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred style, as I really dislike the `this.` pollution.